# Why does getElementById().value not returning the element correctly?

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementbyid

I usually use jQuery but am starting to develop in pure javascript. I'm trying to create a variable for an element that I can use throughout the code but I can't seem to get it working. At the moment I'm trying:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').value;
```

Then using that variable like:

```
canvas.style.backgroundPosition = '0 0';
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong that is cause the variable to not be read or not declared properly?

Comment: Because canvas has the value and not the DOM element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element.value` returns the value as a string, not the element (and a canvas has no value).
For just the element remove the `.value` part

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

canvas.style.backgroundPosition = '0 0';
```